# Retrieve server IP address using gethostbyname()

Tags: sockets, network-programming, gethostbyname

### I'm trying to retrieve the server IP address using gethostbyname(required from me)

here is the part of the client application for connecting to the server

```
        struct hostent *SN =  gethostbyname(argv[1]);

        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(*SN->h_addr); //I have a doubt about this line

        int serverfd=0;
        serverfd = connect(SocketD, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, 
        sizeof(server_addr));
```

where `argv[1]` is the name of the server, currently `localhost`.

I tried also this line of code

```
server_addr.sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*)SN->h_addr;
```

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I tried also server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = **htons** (*SN->h_addr);

Comment: What exactly are you running into? Are you getting an error or some other unexpected result?

Comment: so serverfd should be 0 if the connection is successful and -1 if the connection is not successful. I'm getting serverfd=-1. Plus when i run the server application, it's obvious that the server app is not connected to anything. I mean the server app blocks at the accept function.

Comment: Remove the `htonl()` conversion for `h_addr`. It's already in network byte order. `serverFD` isn't an FD, it is a boolean, and its name should reflect that. You don't even need it really.

Comment: serverfd is integer variable, i need it to check if the connection was successful or NOT. Because connect() will return 0  if the connection was successful.

Comment: I understand what it's for thanks. It is still not an FD, and it still should not have FD in its title. Or 'server' either, for that matter. A better name would be `connectStatus`.

Comment: thank you for pointing that, but that won't make the program works!